# Should the optimization tag be re-purposed away from "query optimization" and towards "general" system-level optimization?

Tags: discussion

[optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) has this in the tag excerpt:

> In the context of a database, optimisation refers to the process of the query optimiser selecting an efficient physical execution plan.

However, there is another tag, [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) which is quite similar:

> Query optimization is a function of many relational database management systems. The query optimizer attempts to find an efficient way to execute a given query by considering the possible query plans.

I proposed a synonym be created to point [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) at [optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) - however the point was [raised in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22216317#22216317) that perhaps the two tags *should* be different.  I agree with that point.

[optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) has 510 questions; these questions should likely be retagged with [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization)

The tag wiki for [optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) needs to be modified to be more generic; and perhaps the tag excerpt should guide users towards the [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) tag for those types of questions.

Thoughts?

Comment: So are there any questions on the site we'd currently tag [tag:optimization] if we went with your idea?

Comment: Here's one that sits on the fence:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248703/script-optimization-for-massive-updates  The solution needs broader optimization than simply fixing a query.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that optimization should always be shorthand for query-optimization - there is a significant amount of DBA work on many other sorts from hardware, storage, block sizes through indexing/MVs/etc as well.

I suggest [optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) is a synonym for [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) rather than the other way round, and then other tags such as [hardware-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-optimization), [io-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/io-optimization) or whatever can exist on their own if and when they are justified — eg [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12675/mysql-reads-writes-per-table) isn't about query-optimization.

We could just have a generic [database-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-optimization) to cover all optimization that doesn't fit in [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization)?

Answer (score 5):

I agree [optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) (510 questions) and [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) (82) should be synonyms, [as Jack suggests](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1278/1192).

But, they should be used **only** for questions about the operation of the **query optimizer/planner** component, in line with the current wiki excerpt and description.

The word *optimization* is often used (especially colloquially or by beginners) when the intended meaning is closer to *performance improvement*. For those questions, the more popular [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) (1534) or [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) tags (835) may be more appropriate.

Though it might mean fighting a losing semantic battle, this answer suggests:

- [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) should be reserved for the query optimizer/planner component.
- [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) and related tags should be used for questions about improving performance.
- New tags about improving performance should use the word "performance" rather than "optimization".

The existing [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) and [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) wikis should be amended to reflect this distinction, and guide people to the correct tag.

Answer (score 4):

I agree the more generic [optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) should could be about optimal server/db settings, optimizing your disc system, or any number of other things. I think they should be seperate and have the wiki updates.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer `server-optimization` as the tag for server related issues.  I prefer this over `hardware-optimization` since it focuses on the server environment overall rather than on the hardware in itself.

This focuses on systemic problems in the server environment, which would also include such things as network through-put, virtualization problems, the underlying server hardware, SAN behavior, and so forth.

I do agree with Jack Douglas and Paul White that `optimization` means `query-optimization` to most of the people most of the time. And that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect optimization is going to be the general-case for queries, and so does not need specification. I feel like [hardware-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-optimization) or [server-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server-optimization) makes more sense over [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) as 90% of dba optimization is around queries, no?

I'm not saying we don't need to know about, for example, disk layout optimization. I'm just saying it's the outlier, whereas query optimization is the "default"