# Too many "Slow performance" meta tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

Do we really need all these different meta tags for "Slow performance" like:

- performance
- postgresql-performance
- query-performance
- performance-tuning
- optimization
- query-optimization
- slow-log
  etc

Or can we merge some of them to maybe only use:

- performance (postgresql-performance, query-performance)
- optimization (performance-tuning, query-optimization)

Comment: why did you suggest [this edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/146065), where you replaced [tag:performance] with [tag:query-performance]?   By the way, that edit is now rejected as "no improvement".

Answer (score 2):

I like where your head is at. I would rather not break down performance by database, just use multiple tags. I'm not sure how to find all the synonyms for everything (ex: [slow-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-log)) so I would need help identifying more synonyms

---

So, here's a thing: I went ahead and did this thinking "yeah, this is a good idea, let's keep things simple! YAY!" and wasn't actually considering that this has been discussed before :-(

- [Should the optimization tag be re-purposed away from "query optimization" and towards "general" system-level optimization?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/should-the-optimization-tag-be-re-purposed-away-from-query-optimization-and-to)
- [Merge tag:postgresql-performance with tag:query-performance?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/merge-tagpostgresql-performance-with-tagquery-performance)

I pulled this trigger. Some things are now final and can't be undone:

1. [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) merged into [optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)
2. [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) merged into [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
3. [postgresql-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) merged into [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
4. [slow-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-log) merged into [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
5. [performance-testing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-testing) into [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
6. [performance-tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) into [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
7. [pg-basebackup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pg-basebackup) merged into [backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup)
8. [xtrabackup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xtrabackup) merged into [backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup)
9. [netbackup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netbackup) merged into [backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup)

That was stupid on my part. I should have waited like a week at minimum. I, put simply, messed up. I let the community down by being too eager to do something good. I'm sorry guys (and gals).

---

Okay, some of the re-tagging has been undone thanks to Shog9 (community moderator) so some of the original tags are back. We'll have to re-do the tag-wikis, the mods have access to some of that information.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, remove the [postgresql-performance] tag? If so, where can I find its tag description now? I would at least want to add it here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/3684 I have been referring to it a lot to provide guidance. The text is valuable.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Is that what you need? https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/82443/revisions

Comment: @PaulWhiteReinstateMonica: Yes, thanks. I added it with some updates here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter FYI the edit here. Some of the questions for postgresql-performance are back with that tag. The tool may take a bit to run I was told.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Thanks! I added back the tag description for [postgresql-performance], copying from dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684 mentioned above. I *can* live without the tag (though I don't mind having it), but I *need* a prominent place for those instructions, ideally where only competent people can edit. The merge list in your answer seems outdated by now?

Comment: Yeah, I was waiting on the other automation to finish before I went back and completely rechecked everything. Once burnt and all that.... 

Comment: I am not happy that `query-performance` and particularly `slow-log` have been merged.

Comment: I can unwind that ...  open a new question for me please? As you see I screwed up before >.<